# Returning a integer based index of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that searches for a term within a DataFrame and I would like to return an integer based index of the found term, I checked the docs and think that Index.get_loc() should do the trick however I am getting the following error with my code:

```
df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, "files", file), sheet_name=sheet)
for col in df.columns:
    rowfilter = df[col].map(lambda i: str(i)).str.contains("quantity", case=False, regex=False)
    search_row = df[rowfilter].index.get_loc() #This is a 'slice' of the rows containing the search term
    print(search_row)
    #The output should be 6
```

However, I am getting the following error,

```
Index.get_loc() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'
```

I have tried the following:

```
search_row = df[rowfilter].index()
print(pd.Index.get_loc(search_row))
```

But get the same error, So the question is, what is the correct key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an aside, you can simplify your search:

```py
mask = df[col].astype(str).str.contains('quantity', case=False, regex=False)
```

In any case, once you obtain your `mask` (which is a `bool` `Series`), you can get the numerical indices of all the matches:

```py
ix = df.reset_index().index[mask]
```

This will be an `Int64Index`. You can also get it as a `list`:

```py
ixs = ix.tolist()
```

In any case, you can use `ix` or `ixs` for `.iloc` (`df.iloc[ix]`).

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shared the sample data. creating a test dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col" : [1,2,3,4]
})
```

you can get the index value by

```
df[df.col == 1].index.values
```

it will return an array

```
array([0])
```

if there are multiple rows with match

```
df[df.col.isin([1,2,])].index.values
```

it returns

```
array([0, 1])
```

Hope it helps